# IHttpClientFactory and services.AddHttpClient between relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, .net-core

I work on a company's bff project. That's why we throw so many http calls. The project is coded with .Net5 . I saw that HttpClient was used when making Http calls, and I thought it would be better if I created HttpClient using IHttpClientFactory to make socket usage more efficient in best practices.

A DI was made like this for HttpClients in the startup file

```
services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(c =>
                         {
                             c.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.Url);
                             c.Timeout = settings.Timeout;
                         })
                         .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(sp => new DefaultHttpClientHandler())
                         .AddHttpMessageHandler<OutgoingRequestHandler>()
                         .AddHttpMessageHandler(serviceProvider =>
                             new TraceLogHandler(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<TraceLogHandler>>(), settings.Logging));
```

When I hovered the mouse over the AddHttpClient method, I saw the following explanation:

> Adds the IHttpClientFactory and related services to the
> IServiceCollection and configures a binding between the TClient type
> and a named HttpClient. The client name will be set to the type name
> of TClient.

```
    MyHttpClientBase.cs

   public class HttpClientBase<T>
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly ILogger<T> _logger;

        public HttpClientBase(HttpClient httpClient, ILogger<T> logger)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _logger = logger;
        }
   ...}
 

   myApiClient
   public class ApiClient : HttpClientBase<IApiClient>, IApiClient
    {
        public ApiClient(HttpClient httpClient, ILogger<IApiClient> logger)
            : base(httpClient, logger)
        {
        }
        ...
    }
```

I didn't understand that in this usage, the use of Socket manages my IHttpClientFactory. Or is it used with IHttpClientFactory integrated?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is fully correct. You can see source code of it in [official .NET repo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs):

```
public static IServiceCollection AddHttpClient(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    
    // adds HttpClientFactory, HttpMessageHandlerFactory, HttpMessageHandlerBuilder
    services.TryAddTransient<HttpMessageHandlerBuilder, DefaultHttpMessageHandlerBuilder>();
    services.TryAddSingleton<DefaultHttpClientFactory>();
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpClientFactory>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DefaultHttpClientFactory>());
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpMessageHandlerFactory>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DefaultHttpClientFactory>());

    // ...
    
    return services;
}

public static IHttpClientBuilder AddHttpClient<TClient, [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicConstructors)] TImplementation>(
    this IServiceCollection services, string name)
    where TClient : class
    where TImplementation : class, TClient
{
    // ...

    AddHttpClient(services);

    // Creates named HttpClient for the exact TImplementation type, so the type will get only this HttpClient
    string name = TypeNameHelper.GetTypeDisplayName(typeof(TClient), fullName: false);
    var builder = new DefaultHttpClientBuilder(services, name);
    builder.ConfigureHttpClient(configureClient);
    builder.AddTypedClientCore<TClient, TImplementation>(validateSingleType: true);
    return builder;
}
```

Creation and disposing of clients (and, what is more important, underlying handlers) is fully controlled by HttpClientFactory,  you should not do it yourself. This is recommended way by Microsoft. More information about using HttpClients [in official guidelines.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines)

Comment: I used HttpClient like this. Does IHttpClientFactory manage socket usage?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typed-clients, I'm using type Client implementaiton.

Comment: Yes. it does. /

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is the IHttpClientFactory will drive the socket as needed when you instantiate it in a classe with DI by the container that is created with this implementation.

The factory method, introduce messages handlers, that will be who will manage request and websockets available to use.

[image]

Comment: I used HttpClient like this. Does IHttpClientFactory manage socket usage?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typed-clients, I'm using type Client implementaiton.

Comment: Yeah, when you create a DI in service collection adding "services.AddHttpClient()" despite de name AddHttpClient, this introduce the Ihttpclientfactory middleware, the basic usage will make this works with the managed pools. But you have to check, when you will instantiate a http object in classes that you'll need to inject IHttpClientactory  not Httpclient

Answer (score 0):

I examine the .net source code and I saw IHttpClientFactory used in the above usage.

```
public static IHttpClientBuilder AddHttpClient<TClient, [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicConstructors)] TImplementation>(
        this IServiceCollection services, Action<HttpClient> configureClient)
        where TClient : class
        where TImplementation : class, TClient
    {
        if (services == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }

        if (configureClient == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configureClient));
        }

        AddHttpClient(services);

        string name = TypeNameHelper.GetTypeDisplayName(typeof(TClient), fullName: false);
        var builder = new DefaultHttpClientBuilder(services, name);
        builder.ConfigureHttpClient(configureClient);
        builder.AddTypedClientCore<TClient, TImplementation>(validateSingleType: true);
        return builder;
    }


internal static IHttpClientBuilder AddTypedClientCore<TClient, [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicConstructors)] TImplementation>(
    this IHttpClientBuilder builder, bool validateSingleType)
    where TClient : class
    where TImplementation : class, TClient
{
    ReserveClient(builder, typeof(TClient), builder.Name, validateSingleType);

    builder.Services.AddTransient(s => AddTransientHelper<TClient, TImplementation>(s, builder));

    return builder;
}

[UnconditionalSuppressMessage("ReflectionAnalysis", "IL2091:UnrecognizedReflectionPattern",
    Justification = "Workaround for https://github.com/mono/linker/issues/1416. Outer method has been annotated with DynamicallyAccessedMembers.")]
private static TClient AddTransientHelper<TClient, TImplementation>(IServiceProvider s, IHttpClientBuilder builder) where TClient : class where TImplementation : class, TClient
{
    IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory = s.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    HttpClient httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(builder.Name); // This Line

    ITypedHttpClientFactory<TImplementation> typedClientFactory = s.GetRequiredService<ITypedHttpClientFactory<TImplementation>>();
    return typedClientFactory.CreateClient(httpClient);
}
```